# Trying to add spark and use sparkSession on spring application produces internal error

Tags: java, apache-spark, tomcat

I do not have spark installed I'm using a `maven` dependency, this is my `pom.xml` content:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I only added the `log4j` dependencies because i was getting another error.

I'm trying to make the simplest usage of sparkSession just to create a dataFrame for now.

this is the code that is producing the internal error:

```
        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("example").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
```

At first run i get this error:

```
"Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_9"
```

but after i try re-running the request i keep getting this one error:

```json
{"code":"INTERNAL_ERROR","message":"Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$"}
```

I'm running this java version:

```
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

but on eclipse's tomcat server i have `tomcat v8.5 JDK 11`

I'm just trying to put a list of a POJO into a dataframe to later do some aggregations and group by on it. And then make an excel file. I'm not sure if using Spark is the best option.

If I keep running the request I just see this on the log:

```
2023-07-31 14:33:16,841 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [INFO ] org.apache.spark.util.Utils - Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 49350.
```

and each time it's a different port number.